# jQuery.ajax chama webmethod(c#) com SpeechSynthesizer

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, webmethods

Eu tenho um método javascript que verifica se existe uma mensagem não lida. Se existir exibe a imagem de um envelope.

O metodo executa um jQuery.ajax que chama um WebMethod que retorna a quantidade de mensagens não lida.

Porém agora preciso adicionar no WebMethod o SpeechSynthesizer(C#) para falar as mensagens não lida. Porém quando adiciono essa funcionalidade o success, complete ou erro do jQuery.ajax não são executados, e eu não sei como resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver dessa forma:
$.ajax({url: "seu WebMethod ", success: function(result){
   if('speechSynthesis' in window){
      var speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(result);
      speech.lang = 'pt-BR';
      window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
    }
}});